# regex for the last one or two digits in r

Tags: regex, r

Is it possible to use regex on the following vector:

```
u<-c("first1","sec2","thir33","fourth4","fifth25","sixth16",
     "seven7","eight8","nine9","ten10","eleven11")
```

to obtain:

```
[1] "first.1" "sec.2" "thir3.3" "fourth.4" "fifth2.5" "sixth1.6" "seven.7" "eight.8"
[9] "nine.9" "ten.10" "eleven.11"
```

This is as close as I've gotten:

```
gsub("([A-Za-z]*)([1]{0,1})([0-9]$)","\\1\\.\\2\\3",u)
#[1] "first.1"   "sec.2"     "thir3.3"   "fourth.4"  "fifth2.5"  "sixth.16"  "seven.7"   "eight.8"   "nine.9"    "ten.10"   
#[11] "eleven.11"
```

Note the sixth element is incorrect: "sixth.16" should be "sixth1.6".

Comment: Not a full answer, but this grabs the numbers at the end: `[\d]+$`.

Comment: Actually `(\d)$` will capture the last digit.

Comment: There's more than a single digit at the end though.. ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see an internal regex method that would "know" or have access to the position in a vector, but can certainly pass it in and use its 'as.character' coerced value in a pattern.

```
sapply(seq_along(u), function(x) sub(
                                     paste("(^.+)(", as.character(x), "$)", sep=""),
                                     "\\1.\\2", u[x]) )
 [1] "first.1"   "sec.2"     "thir3.3"   "fourth.4"  "fifth2.5"  "sixth1.6"  "seven.7"   "eight.8"   "nine.9"   
[10] "ten.10"    "eleven.11"
```

Comment: This took me a while to understand; it's quite clever. You aren't using one regex, but you're using `sapply` to use a different regex for every element.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't particularly pretty, but you can do it in one step with:

```
gsub("([A-Za-z]+)(10|11)?(?:(\\d)(\\d))?([0-9]{0,1}?)$","\\1\\3\\.\\2\\4\\5",u)
```

Alternatively, you can break it up into a few steps. Take the single-digits first, then handle the 2-digit cases separately.

```
v <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+)(\\d)$","\\1.\\2",u)
v <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+)(10|11)$","\\1.\\2",v)
v <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+\\d)(\\d)$","\\1.\\2",v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DWin's answer as a jumping off point, you could gain some speed (assuming your real problem tackles a much longer vector) by knowing that elements 1:9, 10:99, 100:999 and so on should all be handled in the same respective way.

So, get some larger data

```
u<-c("first1","sec2","thir33","fourth4","fifth25","sixth16",
     "seven7","eight8","nine9","ten10","eleven11")
u[12:101981]<-NA

set.seed(1)
for(i in 12:101981)u[i]<-paste0(paste(sample(c(LETTERS,1:9),5),collapse=""),i)

lengthu<-length(u)
maxLength<-nchar(lengthu)
theStart<-10^(seq_len(maxLength)-1)
theEnd<-c(theStart[-1]-1,lengthu)
```

Then use `sapply` not over each element in `u`, but rather over a sequence of length `maxLength`

```
tempans<-sapply(seq_len(maxLength),function(x){
  sub(paste0("(^.*)(\\d{",x,"})"),"\\1.\\2",u[theStart[x]:theEnd[x]])
})
tail(unlist(tempans))
# [1] "DWY96.101976" "UWFCO.101977" "UR5L8.101978" "XBQ9V.101979" "48MTI.101980"
# [6] "75LIS.101981"

head(unlist(tempans))
# [1] "first.1"  "sec.2"    "thir3.3"  "fourth.4" "fifth2.5" "sixth1.6"
```